# How to test HOC with enzyme, chai

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, chai

I have a HOC function that receives a React component and returns that react component with two new method properties (`handleBack` & `moveitOnTop`) like so:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

 export default WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
            this.moveitOnTop = this.moveitOnTop.bind(this);
            this.handleBack = this.handleBack.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            isSearchActive: false
        };
    }
    moveitOnTop(flag) {
        this.setState({ isSearchActive: flag });
        window.scrollTo(0, -100);
    }

    handleBack() {
        this.setState({ isSearchActive: false });
        if (document.body.classList.contains("lock-position")) {
            document.body.classList.remove("lock-position");
        }
    }

    render() {
        const props = {
            ...this.props,
            isSearchActive: this.state.isSearchActive,
            moveitOnTop: this.moveitOnTop,
            goBack: this.handleBack
        };

        const classes = classNames({ "c-ftsOnTop": this.state.isSearchActive });
        return (
            <div className={classes}>
                <WrappedComponent {...props} />
            </div>
        );
    }
  };
 };
```

The component:

```js
 //import fireAnalytics
import { fireAnalytics } from "@modules/js-utils/lib";
class MyComponent extender Component{
  constructor(){
     super(props);
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

   handleClick(e) {
     // calling analytics function by passing vals
    fireAnalytics({
        event: "GAEvent",
        category: "",
        action: `Clicked on the ${e.target.id} input`,
        label: "Click"
    });

     // I CALL THE HOC PROPERTY
     this.props.moveitOnTop(true);

     // I CALL THE HOC PROPERTY
     this.props.handleBack();
   }

  render(){
     return(
        <div className="emailBlock">
          <input type="text" onClick={handleClick} />
          <Button className="submit">Submit</Button>
        </div>
     )
  }
}

// export HOC component
export default hoc(MyComponent);

// export just MyComponent
export {MyComponent};
```

I want to test the HOC:

1. I need to check that class `.c-ftsOnTop` exists
2. I need to check `onClick` function that calls `this.props.handleBack` & `this.props.moveitOnTop'
3. I need to check if className `emailBlock` exists.

The test that I tried, but fails:

```js
 import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
 import sinon from 'sinon';
 import React from 'react';
 import { expect } from 'chai';
 import hoc from '....';
 import {MyComponent} from '...';
 import MyComponent from '....';

 it('renders component', () => {

const props = {}
const HocComponent = hoc(MyComponent);
const wrapper = mount(
  <HocComponent {...props} />
);

console.log('wrapper:', wrapper);
expect(wrapper.find('.c-ftsOnTop')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
expect(wrapper.hasClass('c-fts-input-container')).toEqual(true);
 })
```

Error

`AssertionError: expected {} to have a length of 1 but got 0`

console.log:  `wrapper: ReactWrapper {}`

Can anybody help me on how to render the HOC?

Comment: Why would the class be added? The state property that would toggle it on defaults to false, right? Have you looked at the debug or html methods to see what's being rendered?

Comment: Can you use mocks for your input and output components?

Comment: I think this kind of testing (of implementation details) shouldn’t be encouraged and instead you should test what the user of your component cares about, such as an element being there when the right props are passed, etc. I suggest you take a look at react-testing-library from Kent C Dodds and check out the examples to test HOCs, it is way simpler and as effective or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working test:

```js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import WrappedMyComponent from './MyComponent';

it('renders component', () => {
  const props = {}
  const moveitOnTopSpy = jest.spyOn(WrappedMyComponent.prototype, 'moveitOnTop');
  const handleBackSpy = jest.spyOn(WrappedMyComponent.prototype, 'handleBack');
  const wrapper = mount(
    <WrappedMyComponent {...props} />
  );

  // 1. I need to check that class .c-ftsOnTop exists
  wrapper.setState({ isSearchActive: true });  // <= set isSearchActive to true so .c-ftsOnTop is added
  expect(wrapper.find('.c-ftsOnTop')).toHaveLength(1);  // Success!

  // 2. I need to check onClick function that calls this.props.handleBack & `this.props.moveitOnTop'
  window.scrollTo = jest.fn();  // mock window.scrollTo
  wrapper.find('input').props().onClick();
  expect(moveitOnTopSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  expect(window.scrollTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0, -100);  // Success!
  expect(handleBackSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!

  // 3. I need to check if className emailBlock exists
  expect(wrapper.find('.emailBlock')).toHaveLength(1);  // Success!
})
```

---

**Details**

`.c-ftsOnTop` is only added when `isSearchActive` is `true` so just set the state of the component so the class is added.

If you create your spies on the prototype methods for `moveitOnTop` and `handleBack`, then when the `hoc` creates its instance methods by binding them to `this` in the constructor, the instance methods will be bound to your spies.

`window.scrollTo` logs an error to the console by default in `jsdom` so you can mock it to avoid that error message and to verify that it was called with the expected arguments.

---

Note that the above test requires the following typos to be fixed in `MyComponent`:

- `extender` should be `extends`
- `constructor` should take a `props` argument
- `onClick` should be bound to `this.handleClick` instead of just `handleClick`
- `handleClick` should call `this.props.goBack()` instead of `this.props.handleBack()`

(I'm guessing `MyComponent` was just thrown together as an example of the actual component)

Comment: yes, thank you.
I forgot to mention that inside `handleClick` there are also other things there, like calling another function before calling `moveitOnTop`, e.g `fireAnalytics(a,b,c,d)` . So can i mock this func like  `const fireAnalytics = jest.fn();` . ?

Comment: Is `fireAnalytics` a function that gets imported into your component?  If so, then yes, you can mock it from your test file.  @TheoItzaris

Comment: Actually its a module and i use the function.I updated the code, i call `fireAnalytics` into handleClick.
If i just mock it into the test i think its not enough, i also need to inject it into the component somehow ?